# Geographic clustering of randomly selected sample points

Tags: r, spatial, random, spatial-query

I have a table of available sampling stations with unique identifier `GRID_ID` as well as the latitude and longitude (and UTM) of each station. I would like to randomly select a subset of these stations, which I can easily do using `sample()`.

However, to maximize efficiency, I would also like to employ some clustering by  specifying that any randomly selected sampling station must be within `x` distance of at least `y` other stations.

The rationale is that it makes sense to travel a long distance to sample a group of `y` stations, but it does not make sense to travel a long distance to sample `< y` stations.

Does this make sense?  Is there a straightforward way to handle this in R?

Comment: This [article](http://www.r-bloggers.com/spatial-clustering-with-equal-sizes/)  might point you in the right direction.

Comment: I don't think "cluster analysis" is the appropriate term here. Instead, consider a two stage sampling process: first sample the travel destinations (<< y), then sample neighbor stations to include from those within radius x of your seed sample.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
# some random data
set.seed(1) 
df <- data.frame(x=runif(10), y=runif(10))

# e.g. select obs that have >= 1 neighbour closer than .3 (euclidean)
mat <- as.matrix(dist(df))
sel <- rowSums(mat < .3) >= 2 
plot(y~x, df, col = sel + 1L) # viz

# e.g. select obs that have >= 2 neighbours closer than 40000 (great circle/lon,lat)
library(geosphere)
mat <- distm(as.matrix(df))
sel <- rowSums(mat < 40000) >= 3 
plot(y~x, df, col = sel + 1L) # viz

# Take 2 random obs from those who meet the criteria
df[sample(which(sel), size = 2), ]
```

---

Ok, calculating a distance matrix between ~31000 data points probably choke an ordinary computer. Another approach could be using density based clustering like DBSCAN. It could look like this:

```
# load your data
set.seed(1)
download.file("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17339799/MHI_BF_Survey_Domain_PSU.txt", tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv"))
fullds <- read.csv(tf)
df <- fullds[, c("lon_deg", "lat_deg")]

library(dbscan)
kNNdistplot(as.matrix(df), k=4) # determine eps value...
```

[image]

```
res <- dbscan(as.matrix(df), eps = .005, minPts = 4, borderPoints=F)
# DBSCAN clustering for 31083 objects.
# Parameters: eps = 0.005, minPts = 4
# The clustering contains 134 cluster(s).
# Available fields: cluster, eps, minPts

noise <- res$cluster == 0
sum(noise)
# [1] 2499

# interactive plot with zoom 
# (draw rectangle with right mouse, 
# CTRL to reset)
library(iplot)
iplot(df$lon_deg, df$lat_deg, col=noise + 1L)
```

[image]
[image]

You probably have to tune it to fit your needs. But

```
idx <- sample(which(!noise), 250)
fullds[idx, ]
```

would then give you the sample.

Comment: This looks like a good method, although my initial set of available sampling stations is a grid (fishnet) so any given station will have multiple adjoining neighbors before random selection takes place.

Comment: I've uploaded an example of the sampling station grid to: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17339799/MHI_BF_Survey_Domain_PSU.txt

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what the data set is about. I see geo coordinates around some islands, but that's it. Maybe you can rephrase your question in the veins of "I need a sample of n lat_deg/lon_deg rows grouped by x" or something. All in all it's probably best to post a new question - including the data plus a reproducible example of what you tried.

Comment: thank you lukeA.  This is simply a grid of ~31000 equally spaced points covering the Main Hawaiian Islands. I need to randomly select ~250 of these points for sampling, but I need to somehow restrict the random sampling such that the result excludes single points or small groups (<4 points) that are far away from any other points.

I am new to StackOverflow so I apologize for my naiveté.  Is there a way to post data other than my DropBox link?

Comment: DropBox is perfectly ok. To get answers to your questions, it's always advisable to include the (relevant part) of your data or a sample of it that let's the users reproduce your problem easily via copy/paste. I edited the post to show another approach. (Although I must admit that I got not much experience with density based clustering) Also note `download.file` and `read.csv`, which your should include in another post - if you plan one.